# Symlinking react modules with npm link for local development gives error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

During development of my `React` `npm` module, I symlinked it with `npm link`.
After doing this, the package gets linked correctly and also appears in the consumers app `node_modules`.

The module exposes an interface to create a `React` component. Because I'm using `React`, `jsx` and `es2015`, I'm using `babel` to transpile my module code in the pre publishing stage, using the `npm prepublish hook`.

However, when I try to build my consumer app with `webpack` (i.e. after linking it) an error occurs in my package stating:

> Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"

Now the funny part is that if I publish the package on npm, then `npm install` from the registry in my consumer app, build it, everything works fine.

I tried installing the `babel-preset-es2015` in my consumer app, but then it starts complaining about not finding `babel`:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel'

Again, if I install it from the npm registry everything works fine, no errors are thrown during build.

I also tried installing `babel-core`, `babel-cli` and `babel-polyfill`, all to no avail.

I'm using `babel v6.1.x` everywhere and aware of all the recent changes, however I guess I'm missing something obvious and would really appreciate it if someone can help me out, because continuously publishing the module in order to test if stuff works is just bad practice.

For completeness sake here is the code:

- [module](https://github.com/danillouz/react-leafbox)
- [consumer app](https://github.com/danillouz/mapp)

These are the steps I follow to link the module:

1. `cd ~/Sites/me/react-leafbox`
2. `npm link`
3. `cd ~/Sites/me/mapp`
4. `npm link react-leafbox`
5. `npm start`

Stack trace after building:

```
ERROR in ../react-leafbox/lib/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:329:17)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:289:12)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:223:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:366:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:410:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
    at new File (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
    at transpile (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/daniel/Sites/me/mapp/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:83:14)
 @ ./src/js/components/App.jsx 2:10-34
```

Stack trace after adding extra babel related dependencies (which I believe should't be necessary, because they're available in the react-leafbox module):

```
ERROR in ../react-leafbox/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel' in /Users/daniel/Sites/me/react-leafbox/lib
 @ ../react-leafbox/lib/index.js 8:11-39
```

I'm using `node v5.0.0` with `npm v3.3.6` on `MAC OSX El Capitan v10.11.1`. I also tried using `node v4.2.1` with `npm 2.14.7`, which gives me the same errors.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Comment: @FelixKling I missed that one, thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I discovered this in the webpack [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module):

> IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource
>   which they are applied to. This means they are not resolved relative
>   the the configuration file. If you have loaders installed from npm and
>   your node_modules folder is not in a parent folder of all source
>   files, webpack cannot find the loader. You need to add the
>   node_modules folder as absolute path to the resolveLoader.root option.
>   (resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") })

After adding the `root` option to the `webpack.config.js` the error about not being able to resolve `babel` disappeared. Instead I got a new one saying it can’t resolve `react`. I have it defined as a peer dependency, which made me think it needs to fallback when it can’t find it locally, then I found this in the [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-fallback):

> resolve.fallback A directory (or array of directories absolute paths),
>   in which webpack should look for modules that weren’t found in
>   resolve.root or resolve.modulesDirectories.

I combined these two options in the `webpack.config.js` of my consumer app and it worked!

```
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "build.js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query:
                    {
                        presets:[ 'react', 'es2015' ]
                    }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ],
        fallback: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
    },


    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
    }
};
```

I hope this helps anyone coming across a similar issue.

**Update for Webpack ^2.5.0**

Remove the `resolveLoader` Object and replace `resolve.fallback` with `resolve.symlinks` set to `false`:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ],
    symlinks: false
}
```

Comment: The top link seems to be broken

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev That's weird, they work for me, these are the links: 1. http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module and 2. http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-fallback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was just a spelling error but it should be babel-preset-es2015 not babel-preset-2015. npm install babel-preset-es2015.

Comment: was a spelling error, good catch though! it's spelled correctly in my `package.son` however

Comment: there is spelling error in your `package.son` ... just joking :D thank for resolving my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, turns out I had installed globally when I needed to install it to my app dir with `npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

Comment: Ok, wasn't my problem though, I also had it installed locally and made sure it's not installed globally. However my solution works for me, no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when trying to set up the router demo: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up

All the solutions here didn't work for me, but what did was adding a .babelrc file with this as a content:

{
    "presets": [
        "react"
    ]
}